# Usb sound inbuilt with camera not detected in raspbian jassie 2016-02-26

Tags: audio

I am using an inbuilt mic with  USB camera module & I just plug it to the usb port & use in my linux mint for recordings. When I typed in   "cat /proc/asound/modules" in raspberry pi it gives the following answer "0 snd_bcm2835".I think my usb mic input is not detected.Camera woks.Any solution